# Access sql server without directly permission in domain from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Here is the situation. All the machines and users are in the same domain.**We are in a domain enviroment**. There are some sql server 2005/2008 storing data. There is a ASP.NET site in the domain using the Window Authentication. Now, we need read the data from the sql server and display them using SqlDataSource and GridView. But most of users do not have the direct permission to access the database. Is there any solution to get the data from database and display them on the site without granting users permission?

Best Regards,

Comment: Now, I might misunderstand the problem, but don't you just need to create a database user (in SqlServer) and use its credentials in your web apps connection string? End user credentials don't have anything to do with access to the database...

Comment: I am in a domain enviroment using window Authentication. You solution can not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - create a SQL user on the database server, and use this one SQL user account to access the database for all your users (who use their domain accounts to authenticate to your system).

This is a very common situation, and it allows you to easily fine grain the access available to that one account, rather than trying to manage multiple domain style accounts on your SQL server.

Plenty of connection string options here:

http://www.connectionstrings.com

Also a pretty decent MSDN article on the same here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998300.aspx

Comment: The example you provide is SQL Authentication, not Window Authentication.

Comment: Indeed - you asked for a method of doing this that didn't involve granting users permissions on the SQL box (which would be windows authentication).

Comment: SQL Authentication allows you specify a user and password in the connectstring, but you can not specify a user in connect string

Comment: @Yongwei Xing - yes, that's right. You set up a sql user and use that username/password to connect for everybody.  The user context that logs into the application is not used at all.  If you absolutely need the user context for your connection, then you will need to use windows auth.

Comment: @Yongwei Xing - I think you are missing a point here. The user connect to you app and your domain using their windows credentials. Inside the app, specify the username/password, in the connection string, created to access the database.

Comment: @Frank I think it's a little complex in my case. Actually,I am in SharePoint.

Comment: @Yongwei Xing - I don't think that having this in Sharepoint should really make a difference.  The principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but if what you are trying to avoid is explicitly having to grant database permissions each user individually, you can get around this by granting permissions to a Active Directory security group of which all the users you need to grant access to are a member. The individual users will inherit permissions from the group.

However, there's another problem here which may mean that enabling SQL authentication is a simpler solution. Unless Kerberos authentication is enabled in the domain (or the web server is on the same physical machine as the database server), the web server will not be able to pass the users' credentials on to the database server for authentication - the so-called double hop problem. Google for "windows double hop" for more information.